# Speak function isn't working in this command

Tags: python, pycharm

Why the **speak()** function isn't working in this command?
I want to use print and speak of random results at the same time.
Don't know why is it speaking "none".

```
 elif 'how are you' in query:
         results = print(random.choice(["I'am Fine, Thanks for asking. I hope you're fine too.\n Let me know if I can help you with something", "I'am Good, Thanks. What can I do for you?", "I am great, thanks for asking", "How may I help you?" ]))
         speak(f" {results}")
```

Comment: ```print``` returns ```None``` which is assigned to ```results```

Comment: It's printing correctly and randomly but not speaking the printed text. What should I do?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `print` returns `None`, which is assigned to `results`. So it is indirectly doing `results = None` which is then spoken.

Split them up by assigning the random choice, then printing them.

```
results = random.choice(["I'am Fine, Thanks for asking. I hope you're fine too.\n Let me know if I can help you with something", "I'am Good, Thanks. What can I do for you?", "I am great, thanks for asking", "How may I help you?" ])

print(results)

speak(f" {results}")
```

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Consider accepting the answer :)